# Variable file name breaks excel sheet creation

Tags: python, excel, file

I've a code which creates an excel in a specific field with 3 sheets:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\folder\test.xlsx') as writer:
    stock_data_full.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1')
    df_final_histo.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet2')
    df_final_ops.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet3')
```

I need the file name to become a varaible and I've done this:

```
file_name = 'test'

    with pd.ExcelWriter(f'C:\\\\Users\\folder\\{file_name}.xlsx') as writer:
        stock_data_full.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1')
        #df_final_histo.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet2')
        #df_final_ops.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet3')
```

Even though the file_name is variable now, I get an error with the sheets creation and It's blowing my mind.  Any other way to make it variable?

Thanks

Comment: `C:\\\\Users` looks off.

Comment: why so many backslashes?

Comment: two should do, I think. or just `fr'...'` with single backslash as you had it originally above.

Comment: With fr works fine.  Furthermore, I had a previous mistake in my code which was part of the problem and thanks to your answers I discovered it.  Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fr' instead of r' or f' works fine.

```
file_name = 'test'

    with pd.ExcelWriter(fr'C:\\Users\folder\{file_name}.xlsx') as writer:
        stock_data_full.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1')
        #df_final_histo.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet2')
        #df_final_ops.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet3')
```

Comment: Just a mistake, works anyway but with 1 backslash is cleaner :)